# Change Request MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `MySQL`, contains 3 parameters:

```
(`ID_Article`, `Designiation`, `ID_LRU`)
```

I fill it by a data in Excel file from `PHP` it contains also the same parameters:

```
`(`ID_Article`, `Designiation`, `ID_LRU`)`
```

The parsing file is work fine. the field `Designiation` is the description of `Articles` and many `Articles` have the same description so the field `Designiation` is repeated many time in my Excel file.

The problem is when I fill my table `MySQL` it takes just one records. For example: I have the 2 records in my Excel file:

```
DIEDIVBIEN  DIVERSBIEN  Composant
DIEDIVBIEN  DIVERSBIEN  Composant
```

Here in my table SQL I find just one line:

```
DIEDIVBIEN  DIVERSBIEN  Composant
```

My request is:

```
if ($articleid == 'DIEPRESTATION' || $articleid == 'DIEDIVBIEN' || $articleid == 'DIEDIVERS' ){
    if(!($this->_db->query("INSERT INTO `article` (`ID_Article`, `Designiation`, `ID_LRU`) VALUES ('".$articleid."', '".$designation."', '".$IdLRU."');")))
        {   
        if ($LRU != 'new'){
            return $this->_db->query(" UPDATE  `FLOOSE`.`article` SET  `ID_LRU` =  '".$IdLRU."' WHERE  `article`.`ID_Article` =  '".$articleid."' AND  `article`.`Designiation` =  '".$designation."' LIMIT 1 ;");
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

How I can change my request to take all the record in the Excel file ?

Comment: do you have some primary_key field ? that will solve the problem , and perhaps you can query also to fetch all data rows which have columns matching..

Comment: 1) The term is "columns", not parameters. 2) You should be using prepared statements—drop the tutorial that taught you to do string concatenation.

Comment: Yes the table contains 2 Primary-key are (ID_Article, Designation)

Comment: @Alvaro Gonzalez Thank you for your remark.  Which are the prepared statements ?

Comment: It should be right there in the documentation of whatever library you are using. But it basically consists on using place-holders in your query: `SELECT authentication_string FROM user WHERE email=? OR login=?` and then pass the actual values in PHP variables (e.g. an array).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your solution.